# Parametric curve on a surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves, curvature

Having trouble interpreting the given.

Let $M$ be a surface with $x(u,v) = (u,v,u^2+v^2)$. Calculate the normal curvature of $\alpha (t) = (\cos t, \sin t, 1)$ on the surface $M$.

Is $\alpha (t)$ to be considered a mapping $\alpha : \ldots \to M$? What does $t$ mean for $u,v$? Is $u = u(t), v= v(t)$?

I am only given the definition of the normal curvature of surface $M$ at point $p\in M$ in the direction of the unit tangent $\overline{s}\in T_pM$ via the Weingarten operator:
$$k_p(\overline{s}) = \langle \mathfrak S _p(\overline{s}), \overline{s} \rangle $$
Is normal curvature a function, then? Evaluated at every point? There are potentially infinitely many tangent vectors at a point. What makes this definition correct?
And probably most important: what is the definition of normal curvature of a parametrized curve on a surface? Is it a function, a number? How does one calculate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $\alpha$ describes a *curve* embedded inside your surface $M$. The function $\alpha : t \mapsto (\cos t, \sin t, 1)$ is a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^3$, but fortunately, as you pointed out, the image of $\alpha$ is contained inside $M$, which is why it makes sense to think of $\alpha$ not just as a curve in $\mathbb R^3$ but also as a curve on $M$.

The definition you wrote down is the definition of the normal curvature of the surface $M$. However, your question asks you to find the normal curvature of *the curve $\alpha$* on the surface $M$. This is a  quantity defined at every point on your curve. To compute it at a given value of $t$, you should take the $p$ in your formula to be $\alpha(t)$, and you should take the $\bar s$ in your formula to be the unit tangent vector $ \widehat{\alpha ' (t)} = \alpha'(t)/|\alpha(t)|$ to the curve at time $t$. Thus the normal curvature to the curve $\alpha$ on $M$ is the function,$$t \mapsto \left\langle  \mathfrak S_{\alpha(t)} \left( \widehat{\alpha ' (t)}\right), \widehat{\alpha ' (t)} \right\rangle.$$
This measures the rate at which the normal to $M$ "tilts over" in the direction of the tangent to the curve $\alpha$, as you move along $\alpha$. [Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalCurvature.html) you can find an explicit formula in terms of the first and second fundamental forms.

Comment: On second thought, no, it doesn't make much more sense. The weingarten operator is a 2x2 matrix, whereas $\alpha '(t)$ is a 3x1 matrix. How on earth do you apply $\mathfrak S$ to $\alpha '(t)$?

Comment: @AlvinLepik Good question! Suppose $\vec e_u = \partial_u \vec r$ and $\vec e_v = \partial_v \vec r$ are the two basis vectors for the tangent space. You can write $\widehat{\alpha'(t)} = a \vec e_u + b \vec e_v$ for some choice of $a$ and $b$. You then apply the weingarten operator to the 2-component vector $(a,b)$. This gives you another 2-component vector as your answer - let's call this $(c,d)$. Finally, you need to take the dot product of $c \vec e_u + d \vec e_v$ with $a \vec e_u + b \vec e_v $, which gives a scalar, and this is the final answer!

Comment: @AlvinLepik By the way, it's probably easier to explain this without mentioning the Weingarten operator at all. Let $s \mapsto \gamma (s)$ be a parametrisation of a curve with unit velocity everywhere (i.e. $|\gamma'(s)| = 1$). Suppose this curve is embedded inside a surface. Let $\vec N(s)$ be the unit normal to the surface at the point $\gamma(s)$. Then the normal curvature of the curve inside the surface is simply the map  $s \mapsto - \langle \vec N'(s), \gamma'(s) \rangle$.

Comment: @AlvinLepik ... and to calculate this, you would of course use the change rule. First, if $t$ is a general parametrisation, not necessarily of unit velocity, then we need to correct for this. By the change rule, the normal curvature will be $t \mapsto - (\dot s(t) )^{-1} \langle \partial_u N(t) \dot u(t) + \partial_v N(t) \dot v(t), \dot u(t) \partial_u\vec r + \dot v(t) \partial_v\vec r \rangle$. You can now write this using the first and second fundamental forms, as $t \mapsto \frac{L \dot u^2 + 2 M \dot u \dot v + N \dot v^2}{E \dot u^2 + 2F \dot u \dot v + G \dot v^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations, but there are still problems. I don't understand your notation, especially when you haven't specified what your symbols stand for.
I almost understand the last result. The fundamental forms coefficients are functions of $u,v$. Am I allowed to write $u=\cos t, v=\sin t$, because I know that $\alpha$ lies on the surface?

Comment: I get the tangent space at a point can be viewed as a two dim. vector space, but then you say the basis vectors are actually expressed through some vector $\overrightarrow{r}$? What is $\overrightarrow{r}$ and how do I pronoune the expression $\delta _u\overrightarrow{r}$? Partial with respect to $u$ of $\overrightarrow{r}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58742/discussion-between-alvin-lepik-and-kenny-wong).

Comment: I get the gist of it, though, enough to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @AlvinLepik Sorry about that! $\vec r = (u, v, u^2 + v^2)$, so $\partial_u \vec r = (1, 0, 2u)$, $\partial_v  \vec r = (0, 1, 2v)$, and $N = (\partial_u \vec r \times \partial_v \vec r )/|\partial_u \vec r \times \partial_v \vec r|$. Then you need to compute $\partial_u N$ and $\partial_v N$ as well. These are ALL functions of $u$ and $v$. Then, as you say, you substitute $u = \cos t $ and $v = \sin t$, because you want to evaluate them on the curve.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your understanding is correct (notice that the points of $M$ satisfy the equation $x^2 + y^2 = z$, so $M$ is a round paraboloid around the $z$ axis). The components of $\alpha$ satisfy the same equation; $\alpha$ is seen to be a horizontal circle (it lives at constant height $z=1$) on this paraboloid, similar to how parallels are on the globe.

Comment: Ok, so $t$ and $u,v$ exist independently. Coincidentally, the curve is picked such that it lies precisely on the surface.  Had we picked $\alpha = (\cos t, \sin t, 3)$, this problem would be meaningless?

Comment: For normal curvature of $\alpha$, we fix the parameter $t$, this yields a point on the surface $M$ and we can calculate its normal curvature, then? But that brings me to the next problem. Is the tangent of $\alpha (t)$ always collinear to $\alpha '(t)$. I know it's so on planes. In other words, how do I know, which tangent of $p\in M$ to pick. Is the result invariant w.r.t the choice of $s\in T_p M$?

Comment: @AlvinLepik: It seems that you are confusing the normal curvature of a *surface* with the normal curvature of a [*curve on a surface*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_curves_on_surfaces); it's probably the latter that you want, and this should answer all your questions.